# why the if..else block works only for one time

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I need to check each time before user press "add" button to check if data is entered or not, but my "if...else" block works only one time after that it start accepting blank entries in array..I'm not sure why it fails the next time. any help is appreciable as I'm new to java script.
here is my code snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
    <title>Click the button to add a new el</title>
</head>

<body>

    <label>Enter an New item to add in Stock</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name=" itemName" id="addItemInStock"></input>
    <br>
    <p id="errorMsg"></p>

    <button onclick="addToStock()">Add</button>

    <p id="showList"></p>
    <p id="listCount"></p>


    <script>
        var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
        document.getElementById("showList").innerHTML = fruits;
        var newItem = document.getElementById("addItemInStock");


        function addToStock() {
            if ((newItem.value) === "") {
                document.getElementById("errorMsg").innerHTML = "Blank item cannot be added!!";

            } else {
                document.getElementById("errorMsg").style.display = "none";
                fruits.push(newItem.value);
                document.getElementById("showList").innerHTML = fruits;

                clearAndShow();
            }
        }

        function clearAndShow() {
            newItem.value = " ";
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `"" !== " "` try changing the `clearAndShow()` function to this: `function clearAndShow() {
                            newItem.value = "";
                            }`

Comment: @Kevin Kloet  I diidnt get what you mean..

Comment: an empty string is not the same as an string that contans white space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `clearAndShow` function sets the input elements value to a single space, but the `if` checks for an empty string.

You also set the `display` to none the first time it shows, but never switch it back to `block`

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
    document.getElementById("showList").innerHTML = fruits;
    var newItem = document.getElementById("addItemInStock");


    function addToStock() {
      if ((newItem.value) === "") {
        document.getElementById("errorMsg").innerHTML = "Blank item cannot be added!!";
        document.getElementById("errorMsg").style.display = "block";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("errorMsg").style.display = "none";
        fruits.push(newItem.value);
        document.getElementById("showList").innerHTML = fruits;

        clearAndShow();
      }
    }

    function clearAndShow() {
      newItem.value = "";
    }
```

```html
<label>Enter an New item to add in Stock</label>
  <br>
  </br>
  <input type="text" name=" itemName" id="addItemInStock"></input>
  <br></br>
  <p id="errorMsg"></p>

  <button onclick="addToStock()">Add</button>

  <p id="showList"></p>
  <p id="listCount"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the error visible, as opposite from `'none'`.

```
document.getElementById("errorMsg").style.display = "block";
```

```js
 var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
 document.getElementById("showList").innerHTML = fruits;
 var newItem = document.getElementById("addItemInStock");

 function addToStock() {
   if (newItem.value === "") {
     document.getElementById("errorMsg").style.display = "block";
     document.getElementById("errorMsg").innerHTML = "Blank item cannot be added!!";
   } else {
     document.getElementById("errorMsg").style.display = "none";
     fruits.push(newItem.value);
     document.getElementById("showList").innerHTML = fruits;
     clearAndShow();
   }
 }

 function clearAndShow() {
   newItem.value = "";
 }
```

```html
<label>Enter an New item to add in Stock</label><br>
<input type="text" name=" itemName" id="addItemInStock"></input><br>
<p id="errorMsg"></p>
<button onclick="addToStock()">Add</button>
<p id="showList"></p>
<p id="listCount"></p>
```

Comment: thanks it is working..i'm just curious why displaying an error message is related to if else block to stop execution after first time

Comment: it does not stop to work, it is not displaying the error. you see, that the part prevent from inserting into the array. that works, obviously.

Comment: no..it starts inserting the values in arrray as you can see that ", " are getting added on every click of add ,despite the error message display issue in code

Comment: i changed the value to an empty string in `clearAndShow`, so no insert.

Comment: there is scenario just add one item  in array at first and after that click on add while keeping item empty & you will see that it starts adding the  " ,"  commas , in array list itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your code had just small issue. when you set newItem.value =" " it makes this condition fail newItem.value != "". Hence your AddtoStock function didn't work properly

```
function addToStock() {
  if ((newItem.value) === "") {
    document.getElementById("errorMsg").innerHTML = "Blank item cannot be added!!";

  } else {
    document.getElementById("errorMsg").style.display = "none";
    fruits.push(newItem.value);
    document.getElementById("showList").innerHTML = fruits;

    clearAndShow();
  }
}

function clearAndShow() {
  newItem.value = "";
}
```